# Color and font not accurate on second screen (sony tv 24")

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, fonts, gnome-color-manager

When i connect second monitor ( sony tv 24" ) via hdmi cable,
 
Color on second screen are not accurate and font looks blurry/fuzzy.
Calibrate option for display is greyed out by default.
try changing diffrent resolutions but its getting even bad.

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: You haven't told us which Ubuntu you are using that you wish help with, but I am aware some tv monitors tend to overscan, or look *less-than-perfect* when not used at certain resolutions (which can be a pain to work out, as they don't tell you which resolutions actually look good so time-consuming trial-and-error may be required)

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, yes i have tried all resolution available its only lool little better in 1360 x 768